# Fully uninstall Flash Player

Tags: adobe-flash, macos

I have downloded the Adobe official uninstaller from:

[Adobe official uninstaller](https://helpx.adobe.com/in/flash-player/kb/uninstall-flash-player-mac-os.html#main_uninstall)

It looks slightly outdated talking of MacOS 10.7.
But surprisingly I ran it without errors ( don't laugh at me, I had a few seconds old backup ).

But the job doesn't seem to be finished. I found a few detritus from Adobe staying around. I am not sure I detected all of them.
Moreover I am not confident they won't cause any damage now that I
have at least ripped off a part of the corpse.

Where is the correct full uninstall method of this now dead software?

Comment: You can use EasyFind to search a possible trace of Flash Player in your files.